# How to view the images in an album

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have 3 tables images, albums, and murs, I want to view the images of each album, based on the reference of murs_id which is the id of the murs.

images :
id
albums_id
image

albums :
id
name
image
murs_id

murs:
id
titre

```
$grids = DB::table('images')
                ->select(['image']);
          $grids->join('albums','images.albums_id','=','albums.id');
          $grids->where('albums.murs_id','=','12');
          $grids= $grids->get();
```

> I get this error message : Cannot use object of type stdClass as
>   array.

print_r($grids)

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [image] => af6a8ce73d995a028422293bdc23774e.png ) 
            [1] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 00204bc5330c4f6b84028d23b6e96c09.png ) 
            [2] => stdClass Object ( [image] => b474b62ca932066ee5ac77094c757e74.png ) 
            [3] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 2c24b205b24bb1b47da90c54e2babfdb.png ) 
            [4] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 2d4b78b29ee5abbe103eed7b6b42cbdb.png ) 
            [5] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 6041a1abb83b18d38918fe9c79309596.jpg ) 
        )
```

Comment: error just because of `['image']` or somewhere else for `$grids`?

Comment: how, please more detail?

Comment: `print_r($grids)` and share the result

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [image] => af6a8ce73d995a028422293bdc23774e.png ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 00204bc5330c4f6b84028d23b6e96c09.png ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [image] => b474b62ca932066ee5ac77094c757e74.png ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 2c24b205b24bb1b47da90c54e2babfdb.png ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 2d4b78b29ee5abbe103eed7b6b42cbdb.png ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 6041a1abb83b18d38918fe9c79309596.jpg ) )

Comment: look at this response, you are getting the object, so what u need here, you need to use it as `foreach($grids as $val){echo $val->image;}`

Comment: ah! For me, I have done that $Val[ picture'];

Comment: now i hope issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$grids = DB::table('images')
               ->select('images.image')
               ->join('albums','images.albums_id','=','albums.id')
               ->where('albums.murs_id','=','12')
               ->get();
```

Comment: please check `dd($grids); `

Comment: array:6 [▼
  0 => {#235 ▼
    +"image": "af6a8ce73d995a028422293bdc23774e.png"
  }
  1 => {#236 ▼
    +"image": "00204bc5330c4f6b84028d23b6e96c09.png"
  }
  2 => {#241 ▼
    +"image": "b474b62ca932066ee5ac77094c757e74.png"
  }
  3 => {#242 ▼
    +"image": "2c24b205b24bb1b47da90c54e2babfdb.png"
  }
  4 => {#243 ▼
    +"image": "2d4b78b29ee5abbe103eed7b6b42cbdb.png"
  }
  5 => {#244 ▼
    +"image": "6041a1abb83b18d38918fe9c79309596.jpg"
  }
]

Comment: now you pass the `$grids` into the view and `iterate` on it in the view Like so: `@foreach($grids as $gride) {{ $gride->image  }} @endforeach`

Comment: if you want to show in image tag just simply write : `<img src="{{ asset('your-image-directory/'.$gride->image) }}" alt="">`

Comment: This discussion solved your problem. Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is somewhere later in the using of $grids. With this Code you receive PHP stdClass Objects, you can't do something like ->first() on it.

You can wrap it in a collection like this:

```
$grids= collect($grids->get());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) for the querying database. If you have set relationship properly then you can write as:

```
$grids = Image::whereHas('album', function($q) {
          $q->where('murs_id', 12);
         })->get()
```

To use the relation between `Image` and `Album` add a `album()` function in `Image` class as:

Image.php

```
public function album()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Album::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be accessing $grid values as an array but it's returning an object. Instead of `$grids[0]['image']`, try `$grids[0]->image`.

If you are looping, then

```
foreach($grids as $grid) {
    echo $grid->image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the `$grids`, now you are getting the response which is clearly show you the result in object form not in an array.

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [image] => af6a8ce73d995a028422293bdc23774e.png ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 00204bc5330c4f6b84028d23b6e96c09.png ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [image] => b474b62ca932066ee5ac77094c757e74.png ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 2c24b205b24bb1b47da90c54e2babfdb.png ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 2d4b78b29ee5abbe103eed7b6b42cbdb.png ) 
[5] => stdClass Object ( [image] => 6041a1abb83b18d38918fe9c79309596.jpg ) )
```

So, how can you get the values from object:

```
<?php
foreach ($grids as $value) {
    echo $value->image."<br/>"; // will print all images
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you, For me, I have done that $Val[ picture']; :(